# using custom comparator for STL SET inside class through function pointer

Tags: c++, stl, set

I am trying to create a set with this custom comparator function inside a class

```
bool cmpFunc(const node*  a,const node*  b)
{
    return (a->freqOfAlphabet) <= (b->freqOfAlphabet) ;
}

class huffmanEncoder
{
    set<node*,bool (*)(const node*,const node*)> mset(&cmpFunc) ;// throws error
....
}
```

but I am getting an error as 'expected identifier before ‘&’ token'

the same thing works fine inside main

```
int main()
{
set<node*,bool (*)(const node*,const node*)> mmset(&cmpFunc) ; // works fine
}
```

please let me know the reason behind this error, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write executable code not in functions, and since

```
set<node*,bool (*)(const node*,const node*)> mset(&cmpFunc) ;
```

is a constructor invocation (i.e. executable code), and it isn't in a function (in a `class` declaration) - it isn't allowed.

Use constructor initializer list, to initialize members:

```
class huffmanEncoder
{
    set<node*,bool (*)(const node*,const node*)> mset;
    huffmanEncoder () : mset(&cmpFunc) {}
....
};
```